# find which type of garbage collector is running

Tags: java, jvm

Post JSE 5 ergonomics is intended to automatically select the appropriate type of garbage collector for you (among other things).

I would like to know if there is any way to confirm/know the type of garbage collector and performance goals chosen/current set by the JVM ergonomics.

Comment: was curious about ergonomics, specifically for GC and wanted to see it in action - before creating recommendations for production; tried jvisualvm, no joy.

Answer (score 103):

```
java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -version
```

will show you the default garbage collector.  I have also found the following page useful which [details the default garbage collector for various operating systems](http://www.techpaste.com/2012/02/default-jvm-settings-gc-jit-java-heap-sizes-xms-xmx-operating-systems/#more-3569).

Comment: I see no garbage collector related flags/information in the output of that command. I'm on Windows 7 with Java 1.8.0_45.

Comment: @Zero3 well, what _do_ you see?

Comment: this shows the command line args being used with the jvm, but does not show the garbage collector being used: `[user@server ~]$ java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -version
-XX:InitialHeapSize=2018388928 -XX:MaxHeapSize=32210157568 -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseParallelGC
java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)`  eric wang's answer worked for me

Comment: Wrong answer here. Does not provide a solution.

Comment: @liltitus27 You should look for possible values: +UseParallelGC, +UseSerialGC, +UseConcMarkSweepGC, ..., see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/gctuning/available-collectors.htm#JSGCT-GUID-C7B19628-27BA-4945-9004-EC0F08C76003 for me this answer must be accepted as valid.

Answer (score 35):

*(For **Java <= 8**)*

This command print the GC type of a running JVM:

`jmap -heap <pid> | grep GC`

For modern computer (multiple cpus, big memory), JVM will detect it as server machine, and use `Parallel GC` by default, unless you specify which gc to use via JVM flags explicitly.

e.g

`jmap -heap 26806 | grep GC`

Output:

> Parallel GC with 8 thread(s)

---

### @Update - for Java 9+

(Thanks to *@JakeRobb*'s comment.)

Since Java 9, there are 2 changes relevant to this question:

- Need to use `jhsdb` to attach to a java process or launch a debugger.
  Refer: [jhsdb](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jhsdb.htm)
- The default gc is changed to `G1`.

Command format:

`jhsdb jmap --heap --pid <pid> | grep GC`

e.g

`jhsdb jmap --heap --pid 17573 | grep GC`

Output:

> Garbage-First (G1) GC with 8 thread(s)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. For Java 9 and newer, use `jhsdb jmap --heap --pid <pid> | grep GC`.

Comment: If someone getting error like me - 
Supported versions are <versionX> Target VM is <versionY>
use the jdk installation directory to run the above command, e.g. - 
<JDK_HOME>/bin/jmap -heap <PID> | grep GC (ofcourse for <=Java8)

Comment: I got an error running this on JDK 11 for some reason. Instead, `jcmd <pid> VM.flags` reported the the GC info I was looking for.

Answer (score 25):

```
import java.lang.management.GarbageCollectorMXBean;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.util.List;

public class GCInformation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                    List<GarbageCollectorMXBean> gcMxBeans = ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans();

                    for (GarbageCollectorMXBean gcMxBean : gcMxBeans) {
                            System.out.println(gcMxBean.getName());
                            System.out.println(gcMxBean.getObjectName());
                    }

            } catch (RuntimeException re) {
                    throw re;
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(exp);
            }
    }
}
```

e.g. try following commands to know various GC Type

```
java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags  GCInformation
java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+UseParallelGC GCInformation
java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC GCInformation
java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:-UseParNewGC GCInformation
```

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class GCInformation
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GCInformation

Answer (score 10):

Not a direct answer to your question, but I believe this is what you're looking for.

According to **Java 6** documentation [1](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html) and [2](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html) (not just Java 5):

Reference [1](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html) says:

> On server-class machines running the
>   server VM, the garbage collector (GC)
>   has changed from the previous serial
>   collector [...] to a parallel collector

Reference [2](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html) says:

> Starting with J2SE 5.0, when an
>   application starts up, the launcher
>   can attempt to detect whether the
>   application is running on a
>   "server-class" machine and, if so, use
>   the Java HotSpot Server Virtual
>   Machine (server VM) instead of the
>   Java HotSpot Client Virtual Machine
>   (client VM).

Also, reference [2](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html) says:

> Note: For Java SE 6, the definition of
>   a server-class machine is one with at
>   least 2 CPUs and at least 2GB of
>   physical memory.

From this information, you can know that if the box is a server (according to [2](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html)) then it will be using the parallel GC. You can also infer that it will not change GC during runtime.

You can probably find the right answer for non-server machines if you dig further into the documentation.

Comment: exactly! but have you tried this on a virtual machine? any idea what might happen if I allocated 1.75 cores to an instance?

Comment: I haven't, but my third quote says "at least 2 CPUs" so I'm guessing it will use the serial GC. Regarding your comment "wanted to see it in action - before creating recommendations for production", the recommendation is to always set the GC manually.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the following VM arguments with JDK 14,

```
-Xlog:gc -Xlog:gc*
```

The log will be:

```
[0.008s][info][gc,heap] Heap region size: 1M
[0.008s][info][gc,heap,coops] Heap address: 0x0000000700000000, size: 4096 MB, Compressed Oops mode: Zero based, Oop shift amount: 3
[0.011s][info][gc           ] Using G1
[0.011s][info][gc,cds       ] Mark closed archive regions in map: [0x00000007bff00000, 0x00000007bff7aff8]
[0.011s][info][gc,cds       ] Mark open archive regions in map: [0x00000007bfe00000, 0x00000007bfe50ff8]
[0.027s][info][gc           ] Periodic GC disabled
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-XX:+PrintGC
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
```

This will print what GC is used. In my case it prints:

```
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 348192K->32K(348672K)] 356792K->8632K(1048064K), 0.0111518 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
```

Which means that the **Parallel Garbage** collector is being used for the young generation. "Allocation Failure" means that garbage collection started because there were not enough space in young generation heap part.

Comment: I feel like this answer is incomplete. What part of that printout indicates the Parallel collector? Also, how do you invoke that against a running JVM?

Comment: PS stands for Parallel Scavenge. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/serviceabilityagent/sun/jvm/hotspot/gc_implementation/parallelScavenge/PSYoungGen.html . You can pass those parameters to a new Java process that you start, meaning that you cannot apply it to already running process.

Comment: In that case, I think Eric Wang’s answer is better, as you invoke it against a running JVM, and because it doesn’t assume you can translate impossibly generic abbreviations like “PS”. 

Answer (score 1):

Use the [GarbageCollectorMXBean](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html#getGarbageCollectorMXBeans%28%29)s to obtain [MemoryPoolMXBean](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryPoolMXBean.html)s.

Comment: Well, this doesn't really give you the GC that is in use.  Interestingly though, the 'getVMOption' output for  UseSerialGC, UseParallelOldGC, UseParallelGC, UseConcMarkSweepGC, all report 'false'.

Comment: Sorry, I should have tried it before posting :-(.  I had thought I had used it in the past for this...

Comment: This should give you the GCs that may run against the JVM, by watching the collectionCount attributes you can see if they are being used.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some info about how to [programmatically get GC info](http://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/how_to_programmatically_obtain_gc), but it looks like it may need the name of the GC beforehand. Troublesome.

Edit: try `ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()` and iterate through the returned list. One of these will be active.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve performance  goal you need to check with various GC algorithms.

**Available Collector in Oracle JDK**

-XX:+UseSerialGC

-XX:+UseParallelGC

-XX:+UseG1GC

-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

-XX:UseZGC

**Turning on GC Logging in Java 7 / 8**

`java -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps - Xloggc: <file-path>`

**Turning on GC Logging in Java 9 and Up**

`java –Xlog:gc*:file=<file-path>:filecount=10,filesize=10M`

**Dynamically Turning on GC Logging in Java 9 and Up**

`jcmd <pid> VM.log what=gc output=<file-path>`

Try GC Log analyzing tool for compare GC logs

GC Log Analyzer - http://www.gcloganalyzer.com

Answer (score -4):

You can use `-XX` flag for JRE to choose the garbage collector of your choice.

[Tuning Garbage Collection with the 5.0 Java TM Virtual Machine](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html)

Additionally, you can use [JConsole](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/jconsole.html) to monitor garbage collection.

Comment: I know that you can choose your garbage collector, however, what I'm interested in is finding out which collector was chosen by the JVM for me; who knows, maybe it might even change strategies on-the-fly based on usage!

Comment: @ryan-fernandes from [Garbage Collector Ergonomics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/vm/gc-ergonomics.html), on server-class machines running the server VM, the default GC is parallel collector, else serial collector.