# How can I see what garbage collector is running by looking at gc logs?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

How can I see what garbage collector (CMS, Parallel and so on) is running by looking at gc logs for minor and major collection? I don't have access to the command line options set to java (the sysadm for the appserver wont let me see them). I do have rather verbose gc logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exact format of GC messages depends on JVM version and JVM settings. You can see samples at [Oracle tutorial about GC tuning](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html).

`DefNew` is default collector. It's either serial or parallel, which one is chosen depends, again, on JVM version/settings. You can see your default settings in JDK 6 using `java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -version`. On my system it prints:

```
-XX:MaxHeapSize=1073741824 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+UseParallelGC
```

which means Parallel GC is `DefNew` for me. You can check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5024959/162634) and one of it's answers references [this table](http://www.techpaste.com/2012/02/default-jvm-settings-gc-jit-java-heap-sizes-xms-xmx-operating-systems/#more-3569), may be it will help you.

**UPDATE** Default Old Gen GC in JDK 6 is ParallelOldGC, see [this enlightening pdf](http://www.austinjug.org/presentations/JDK6PerfUpdate_Dec2009.pdf). In particular, you can change Old Gen GC to newer Concurrent-mark-sweep one using `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`
 JVM option.

Comment: I have looked at this document but I cant connect for example DefNew, PSYoungGen or ParOldGen to specific collectors. Where can I find a table of this?

Comment: Because the generations aren't connected with specific collectors.  There's only one.  You need to read about the generational GC model - and get Visual VM running: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2002/jw-0111-hotspotgc.html

Comment: @duffymo: I understand that generations aren't connected with specific collectors. After trying myself I think I see that DefNew means Serial Collector, ParNew means CMS Collector and PSYoungGen means Parallel Collector on young generation. What I am looking for is a translation table for all the options.

Comment: @Victor-Sorokin: Thanks, this is what I need. Just to be sure, will the Parallel GC be the default for both young and old gen in your example?

Answer (score 2):

quoting the book "Java Performance" by Charlie Hunt, the name of the young generation space used in the GC logs changes with the GC used:

```
PSYoungGen => ParallelGC
ParNew =>  CMS
DefNew  => SerialGC
```

I am not sure about G1

Answer (score 1):

You can find GC log samples for all HotSpot JVM garbage collection algorithms in [this article](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/12/garbage-collection-in-hotspot-jvm.html).

`-XX:+PrintGCDetails` should be enabled tosee that level of details in GC log.