# How to know the current GC strategy of the HotSpot jvm?

Tags: java, jvm

How to know the current GC strategy of the HotSpot jvm?
I want to tune the jvm args and test the performance,but i wonder how to know the current strategy of the GC.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024959/find-which-type-of-garbage-collector-is-running : use `java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -version`. @Robert Harvey: this can be solved by Java itself, without any third-party tools, thus I wouldn't say it's offtopic (though it's a duplicate).

Comment: The vote to mark "off topic" sounds like an automated bot. I've seem similar votes before, and if there are such bots they're not very mature IMHO. The question was technical and accurate: how to find out the JVM's GC settings, preferably with tools built into java core. It's not a matter of opinion.