# How does the Java virtual machine decide which method of garbage collection to use?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, garbage

I have read a few articles describing how the Java virtual machine uses different techniques for collecting garbage.

How does the Java virtual machine decide which method of garbage collection to use?

Or, if the decision rests on the programmer, what constitutes changing the method of garbage collection?

Thank you.

(Example of one article: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2078645/java-se/jvm-performance-optimization-part-3-garbage-collection.html)

Comment: A garbage collector is not strictly required by the Java virtual machine specification. Please read - **The Java Virtual Machine**
by Bill Venners, if you are really interested to know about Garbage Collection in JVM.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which GC collector to use via jvm options. Checkout that link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/collectors.html

It contains various information about how to choose a particular collector.

Also you can see this answer to see which collector your jvm uses: [find which type of garbage collector is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024959/find-which-type-of-garbage-collector-is-running)